# Overlay transparent image over Adobe PDF Reader control

Tags: c#, pdf, overlay

I'm trying to overlay a transparent image over the Adobe Reader Control. So I can read the PDF while the image is overlapped.

Currently I have the reader control and an imagebox, I got an overlay button that when I click it is supposed to make the image transparent so I can read the text "through" it, well at least where it's transparent in the image.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.Title = "Open";
        open.Filter = "PDF|*.pdf";

        try
        {
            if (open.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(open.FileName);
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void overlayToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

        pictureBox1.Parent = axAcroPDF1;



    }
}
```

My designer so far:

[image: My designer so far.]

Comment: You want the white area to go transparent on button click?

Comment: Yeah the picturebox backgound should become transparent so I can seethrough it and the Image should be overlayed. I can Photoshop a picture of how I atleast picture the final look

Comment: I would like the picture I want to overlay appear like a watermark, constantly showing aslong as you're reading the PDF

Answer (score 0):

I can see your issue here, You are trying to set the colour of the picture box object to Transparent, this will not affect the image in any way.

Imagine you had no image loaded into your picture box, changing the back colour here will make a difference.

To achieve your desired effect, you will need to photo edit your picture and make a version which has transparency (Lowering Alpha and saving as .PNG). Then once you click your button you need to swap the original image to the newly created transparent image. You can use the line `pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("Path")` in this case.

Comment: Ok, I will try doing that, but when I change the background color on the picturebox to transparent and remove the image, the picturebox shows a gray-white color instead of becoming transparent. And thoughts on why this happens?

Comment: This may mean you would have to use the `BackgroundImage` Property of the picturebox. This will override any background that VS puts on the picturebox by default

Comment: Still nothing close to what I'm trying to achieve. But I think I do have a workaround, it's alittle more work but should do the trick. If I make two forms, making the 2nd form transparent and placing it over the 1st form. I only have to transport functionality from the controls in Form2 to Form1.